# Verificar se dois elementos de uma lista são números

Tags: lista, lisp

Estou a tentar verificar se dois elementos de uma lista de 3 elementos são números.
Quero verificar apenas o segundo e o terceiro elementos da lista.

Tenho o seguinte código e não identifico o erro:

```lisp
 (defun ICidadep (lista)
  (if((numberp (second lista))and (numberp(third lista)))t))
```

Answer (score 1):

A sintaxe do `and` segue a mesma ideia dos outros comandos do Lisp, ou seja, em vez de fazer:

```lisp
(condicao1 and condicao2)
```

O correto é:

```lisp
(and condicao1 condicao2)
```

Então no seu caso seria:

```lisp
(defun ICidadep(lista)
    (and (numberp (second lista))
         (numberp (third lista))))
```

Ou, se quiser usar como condição do `if`:

```lisp
; se forem números, retorna 1, senão retorna zero
(defun ICidadep(lista)
    (if (and (numberp (second lista))
             (numberp (third lista)))
     1 0))
```

Claro que você pode trocar o 1 e 0 pelo que precisar.

Comment: E se eu quiser inserir mais uma condição no if? Tenho de pôr dois and's?

Comment: @MariaAlmeida Se não me engano pode fazer `(and condicao1 condicao2 condicao3)`, veja: https://ideone.com/OtoSug